# -Whatif cmdlet for powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a two part question.

I am looking for the `-whatif` cmdlet in Powershell.
I would like to run a script without the potential to break anything and when I run with the parameter  `-Whatif`

```
  Import-Module : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'whatif'.
```

The second part is, is there a way to list all of the cmdlets that when using the `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to see what cmdlets are available ?

Comment: WhatIf isn't a cmdlet, its a parameter that you build into your scripts/functions/cmdlets. Here is a [link](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-whatif-parameter/) explaining what -Whatif is and how to incorporate it into your scripts

Comment: thank you, I appreciate that

Comment: There's also [Everything you wanted to know about ShouldProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.1) at Microsoft Docs, and [a good number of other links to discussions of ShouldProcess](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+supports+shouldprocess).

Comment: For your second question: 
Get-Command -Module (Get-Module -ListAvailable)

Answer (score 0):

Cmdlets and commands are displayed using `Get-Command`

To find all commands for i.e. the Netadpter module use

```
Get-Command -Module Netadapter
```